# Command Line Tool to Batch Convert .EML/.EMLX/.MBOX to Searchable PDFs?

Tags: email, pdf, file-conversion, ocr

I need to convert about 500k emails into searchable PDFs. By 'searchable' I mean that macOS will be able to scan them for specific words rather than simply treating them as an image. My searches, thus far, for a tool to do this have ended in proprietary database apps and over-priced sketchball x-to-pdf converters which basically perform the built-in macOS functionality of Print To PDF. Is there a single tool or two complementary tools that could be used together in Terminal to just batch convert all the emails to searchable PDFs?

Comment: are those all Windows emails

Comment: No, they are not. Some of them are very old Outlook for Mac and Thunderbird files. The majority are Mac Mail files spanning from about 1995 to today.

Comment: just asking, since Thunderbird lets you export as PDF, so does Outlook, so does mac Mail.

Comment: Mac Mail lets you export either one message at a time, individually, which is not feasible for this quantity of documents, or by merging a folder of emails into one pdf, which is also not desired. The add-on that allowed Thunderbird to batch export individual emails as pdfs has broken, according to user reviews. I haven't used Outlook in years, but would prefer to not convert all the messages an additional time to be readable by Outlook. Also, Date Created Metadata is important to conserve for this scenario.

Comment: I just tried in Mac Mail and selected 50 email and exported them all at once as individual pdf's

Comment: where do you have the .EML and .EMLX files anyway ? on your hard drive ?

Comment: Well, that's good and surprising news! I'll give it a try. All the mail & related database files, old and newer, are on an 8TB drive thunderbolted to my Mac Mini. I think I may have wrecked some of them a year or so ago with an ill-advised rmlint command and I may find that I need to try to dig up copies of some of those zerokb mboxes from other old drives, but I think *almost* everything is ready & available.

Answer (score 6):

I had to do this with ~180 emails, and I used a command tool I found on GitHub that converts .eml to .pdf via .html: https://github.com/nickrussler/eml-to-pdf-converter

It takes a little while to convert each .eml file - 22 minutes for 186 emails with lots of images - so it's probably not helpful for a 500k email task. (Maybe if you're *reeeally* not in a rush and not afraid of multiprocessing!) If it is helpful for you or anyone else, though, here's how I got it to work in the bash command line:

1. `git clone` the repo
2. Install the `wkhtmltopdf` tool from binary (installing with `pip` is insufficient) from here: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
3. From within the cloned repo, generate the email converter .jar file: `./gradlew shadowJar`
4. Run for loop to convert every file in the .mbox (or a directory of .eml):

```
for file in /path/to/mailbox.mbox/*; 
do
   java -jar ./build/libs/emailconverter-2.0.1-all.jar "$file"; 
done
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks! On macOS, a simple `brew install wkhtmltopdf` worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across [How to open eml files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28135/how-to-open-eml-files) on AskUbuntu.
It suggests using munpack, which is part of [mpack](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mpack). It can convert an `eml` to `html` or plain `txt`. There are several tools to convert `html` to a `pdf`. [WeasyPrint](https://weasyprint.org/) is one of them. You can install it via `pip`.
mpack is also available in [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/mpack). Assuming you have Homebrew installed, it's easily installed via:

```
brew install mpack
```

Then run

```
munpack -t <my.eml>
```

Comment: Nice find. Might be worth adding at least one way on how to get from HTML/TXT to PDF from the commandline.

Comment: Fair point. I added a tool. It will all require a little bit of scripting. But with these building blocks it should be doable.