# Convert one .mbox file to PDF or ePub, locally

Tags: email, pdf, file-conversion, epub

I downloaded a large batch of emails using [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/). It generated a single `.mbox` file (about 2 MB).

I would like to read these emails in a single file on my Kobo eReader, which accepts file formats of PDF, ePub, mobi, etc.

How do I convert this `.mbox` file into a single file I can read on the eReader -- preferably in ePub or PDF format? I would prefer to do this through a command line tool and not upload the emails to any server.

[This is a similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346982/command-line-tool-to-batch-convert-eml-emlx-mbox-to-searchable-pdfs), but the answers only cover `.eml` files.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a completely CLI solution, but …

1. Double-click on the .mbox file (or `open file`)
2. Mail.app will open with all the messages in a mailbox.
3. Select all, and File→Export as PDF
4. Each message will be its own PDF file.
5. Combine them into a single PDF as shown in https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/combine-files-into-a-pdf-mchl21ac2368/mac

There are also numerous online services that will concatenate PDFs.

And I have used a "PDF Toolkit" on command line that concatenates (among other things).  But I don't know where to get it—a web search gives me lots of things that aren't it.

Comment: You can also concatinate PDFs in Preview. But your linked example is much easier.